# put different names to each bar in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

How I can rename each bar, I want to have different names. always it appears "bar1", "bar2", etc. this is the name of the series. but I want it to appear in place of those texts, others I want to customize. this is what I do. put different names, if there are 9 bars I want to put different names to the bars, bar1, bar2, bar3, Bar4, Bar5, Bar6, Bar7, Bar8, Bar9. I do not want to repeat
in my example.

[image]

```
series: [{
  name: 'bar1',
  data: [1000, 950, 920, 0, 850],
  color: "#FF0000"
}, {
  name: 'bar2',
  data: [800, 770, 750, 0, 730],
  color: "#000000"

}, {
  name: 'bar3',
  data: [600, 540, 535, 500, 30],
  color: "#00FF00"

},
 {
  name: 'bar4',
  data: [28, 28, 28, 28, 28],
  color: "#00FF00"

}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/05L1n3wb/

Answer (score 1):

This is done by changing `name: 'bar1'` to something you want. If you still need `series.name` to be 'bar1' then you should really think harder about your data model. If you want to change the text displayed based on the contents of `series.name` you can do that with the label formatter or dataLabel formatter.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in previous answer, you can use dataLabels formatter for changing string you are displaying for your columns: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.formatter

You can add custom parameter to your points, like name:

```
 series: [{
      name: 'bar1',
      data: [{
        y: 1000,
        name: 'bar1'
      }, {
        y: 950,
        name: 'bar5'
      }, {
        y: 920,
        name: 'bar9'
      }, {
        y: 0,
        name: 'bar13'
      }, {
        y: 850,
        name: 'bar17'
      }],
      color: "#FF0000"
    }]
```

and inside your dataLabels formatter you can display this parameter:

```
  formatter: function() {
    var string = this.point.name + ' ';
    if (this.y <= 30) {
      string += this.y;
    }
    return string;
  }
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/05L1n3wb/2/